# is there any secure websocket (wss protocol) client browser plugin available?

Tags: plugins, websocket, client, wss

we would like to test  our secure websocket (i.e wss) end point. I am looking for easy tool to test the endpoint. is there browser plugin  available for wss protocol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used "Simple WebSocket Client" chrome plugin to test wss endpoint. If your websocket is using self signed certificate, you to need add that certificate as a trusted certificated in your browser.

I followed below steps to add the self signed in my chrome browser.

suppose your websocket url is "wss://host1:port1/testSocket" . Then type urls as  https:// host1:port1/testSocket
and trust the certificate.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo

Comment: @NicholasBlasgen, thank you, but it didn't work with a server sharing an untrusted/invalid SSL certificate - threw an internal implicit code exception message. The following worked however: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hermes-websocket-client/heiclpadccjamigpdpfpbdkcfnglcjgc/related . In addition, you might find https://www.postman.com/ or similar standalone interesting, too.

Answer (score 4):

[AutobahnTestsuite](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-testsuite) is an automated WebSocket protocol test suite that supports WSS. It is used by most WebSocket implementors to test their implementations for compliance and interoperability.

The project and third-party [Web Application Messaging Protocol](https://wamp-proto.org/) (WAMP) clients are also available at: https://crossbar.io/autobahn

Disclosure: I am original author of the testsuite.

Comment: It does show 404 at this moment. We hope you are safe out there... Please do stay!

Comment: above link is dead and won't come back, but you may find the OSS project here https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-testsuite

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue often enough that I finally created my own barebones GUI for testing websockets. It's called Socket Wrench, it supports

- multiple concurrent connections to servers (with all responses and connections displayed in the same view),
- comprehensive message history to enable easy re-use of messages, and
- custom headers for the initial connection request.

It's available for Mac OS X, Windows and Linux and you can get it from [here](https://asleepysamurai.com/articles/socketwrench?ref=stackoverflow/25985653/a).